# JSSOR - strange caption behaviour during slide transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am developing a slider with jssor. The caption play in transition and play out transition work well but during the slide transition the caption appear again.
I wrote a very simple example only two slides with one caption each, only to show the problem.
Here is the jsfiddle ##edit### this jsfiddle work http://jsfiddle.net/PfV3S/
Here the html code:

```
<div id="slider1_container">
<!-- Slides Container -->
<div class="slides" u="slides">
    <div>
        <div class="caption" data-u="caption" data-t="LOGO" style="width: 470px; height: 220px; top: 130px; left: 675px;">
            <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Business/Pretty%20Office%205/Tests.png" style="width: 256px; height: 246px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="caption" data-u="caption" data-t="LOGO" style="width: 470px; height: 220px; top: 130px; left: 675px;">
            <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Business/Pretty%20Office%205/Tests.png" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the js code:

```
                  var _CaptionTransitions = [];
              _CaptionTransitions["LOGO"] = {
                  $Duration: 1800,
                  $Zoom: 1,
                  $FlyDirection: 9,
                  $Easing: {
                      $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,
                      $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,
                      $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
                  },
                  $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3,
                  $ScaleVertical: 0.3,
                  $During: {
                      $Left: [0, 0.8],
                      $Top: [0, 0.8]
                  },
                  $Round: {
                      $Left: 0.8,
                      $Top: 2.5
                  }
              };

              var options = {
                  $AutoPlay: true, //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                  $DragOrientation: 3, //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0),

                  $CaptionSliderOptions: { //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                      $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$, //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                      $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions, //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                      $PlayInMode: 1, //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                      $PlayOutMode: 3 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                  }
              };

              var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

Here the css code:

```
#slider1_container {
  position: relative; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  float: left; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  width: 1600px;
  height: 600px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.slides {
  cursor: move;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0px; 
  top: 0px; 
  width: 1600px; 
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caption {
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  font-size:36px;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:40px;
}

div.caption > img {
  position:absolute;
  width: 256px; 
  height: 246px; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px;
}
```

I really do not find anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question!
I found it's a bug and I have just got it fixed. Please download the latest version.

Btw, it's better to use class to specify css for 'outer container'.

```
<div id="slider1_container" class="slider1_container">
```